# Where should I store SQL queries in MVC 4?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a MVC4-based project with some SQL-queries. They are currently stored in project resources (*.resx), but it is very hard to edit the queries inside the resource editor.

Is there a specialized SQL query storage? where should I store my queries?

Comment: Why not use stored procedures?

Comment: Can I pass some parameters to stored procedure?

Comment: Yes. It is basic functionality.

Answer (score 3):

You can put your queries in your database as stored procedures. This gives you encapsulation of your database logic - a 'separation of concerns'.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no specialized storage for SQL queries.

Resource files sounds a bit unusual, I would rather put them in constant strings in my code, encapsulated in a datalayer. Possible within each method that uses the SQL queries where parameters are applied, etc.

However I would really recommend avoiding plain old SQL and use Entity Framework or LINQ2SQL instead.

Comment: I have a lot of really big queries for large amount of data - is there any posibility to use EF without performance loses?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it with [T4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx). Now I have `Queries` directory in my project and `SQLGenerator.tt` in it. Here is my template source code:

```
<#@ template  debug="true" hostSpecific="true" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
<#@ Assembly Name="System.Core" #>
<#@ Assembly Name="System.Windows.Forms" #>
<#@ import namespace="System" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Diagnostics" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #> 

<#var sqlScriptsContent = ReadSql(); #>

namespace MathApplication.SQL
{
public class Queries
{
<# foreach(var file in sqlScriptsContent) { #>
    public string <#= file.Key #> = @"<#= file.Value #>";
<# } #>
}
}

<#+ 
public Dictionary<string, string> ReadSql() {
    var filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Host.ResolvePath("."));

    var result = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    foreach (var filename in filePaths) {
        if (filename.EndsWith(".sql")) {
            result[Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename)] = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(File.ReadAllText(filename), @"\s+", " ").Replace("\"", "'");
        }
    }

    return result;
    }
#>
```

This code assembles all `*.sql` files in `Queries` directory to one class.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use Entity Framework as ORM?

It's great technology in a link with ASP.NET MVC.

Also you could move SQL to stored procedures in MSSQL.
In this case I would suggest to use Database Project to store your SQL in your solution.

Anyway storing SQL in code or resources is not a great practice.

Comment: I use Entity Framework, but there is a lot of big queries which was optimized by hands